# Name for data locked for change

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I name a boolean thing (yes/no data only) that should show that the all information is locked for changes for users, but admins can change it.

I have thought about: **locked?**, **readonly?**
Is there any better names?

Comment: That depends what app you're using and has nothing to do with "real" English.

Comment: Do you mean records and documents which are locked because another user already has write permissions to them; or do you you mean records or documents which are designated as read-only for all users; or do you mean those to which a particular user has only read-only permissions? All three of those conditions are different and different terms are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `admin_lock` as the column name, and we show "`LOCKED`" or empty string as the status, and "`Toggle Admin Lock`" for the mouse over of the lock icon the administrator clicks to toggle the boolean.

To answer your question... we didn't find anything better than "`LOCKED`".

Answer (score 0):

I would call such data **protected**, because while it can be changed, this is not casually done.

For example, questions on StackExchange that have attracted low quality answers may be **protected** so that only users with a certain reputation may answer them.